# Keeping some local changes when checking out with --force

Tags: git, git-checkout

**The situation**: I have a local git repository which is a clone of a remote repository. Suppose the repository is tracking (among others) two files, `fileA` and `fileB`.

After cloning the repository, I modify `fileA` and `fileB` locally, but I never stage or commit those changes.

Eventually, I will need to run `git checkout --force origin/master` on the local repository to fetch the newest version from the remote repository. Now all the changes I made locally (on files tracked in the remote repository) will be overwritten.

**The problem**: How can I configure the local repository to always keep changes I made to `fileA`, yet overwrite `fileB`? I basically want `fileA` to be ignored locally although it is a tracked file in the remote repository.

Adding `fileA` to `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` did not work, probably because those two files only prevent files from added to tracking, not from being tracked once they are in the index.

`git rm --cache fileA` did not work either, since `fileA` is still in the index at `origin` and thus will be overwritten locally when I check out.

**tl;dr: I want to instruct git to not touch certain files in my repository even though they are being tracked in a remote repository.**

Comment: `I basically want fileA to be ignored locally although it is a tracked file in the remote repository` ... you can't do this in Git AFAIK.  Files which are tracked in the repo are not ignored, and vice-versa.  Something like update index assume unchanged also would not do what you want, because there could be conflicts when you pull.

Comment: The short answer is "don't do that": instead, layer something atop Git, where you have Git manage the repo over in Location A, and then you manually-or-automatically copy everything-but-certain-files from A to your "real place" B. (But life gets much easier if you just use files that aren't version-controlled for the actual configuration of your deployed software.)